# Finding sums of infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

as stated in the title the series are infinite and im struggle with how to find the common ratio. and first term (kinda) well I want it to be on the form: ar^k where r is the ratio and a the first term

(3+2^n)/(2^(n+2)) (n=1)

any tips on how to get that series on the form ar^k ?

Comment: so basically I tried and manage to get (3+2^n)/(2^n* 2^2)
which is (1/4) * (3+2^n)/2n, and also that is 
(1/4) * (1/2)^2 * (3+2^n)/1

Answer (score 0):

It may help to decompose the series:

$$S = \displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^{k} \frac{3 + 2^n}{2^{n + 2}} = \displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^{k} \frac{3}{2^{n + 2}} + \displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^{k} \frac{1}{4}$$

Going a bit further,

$$S = (\frac{3}{8} + \frac{3}{16} + \frac{3}{32} + \dots + \frac{3}{2^{k+2}}) + (\frac{1}{4} k)$$

So in this case, $a = \frac{3}{8}$ and $r = \frac{1}{2}$. Additionally, the infinite series diverges using the $n$-th term test ($\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{4} \neq 0$)

Comment: I see, and this is a good method the problem appears when I need to find the common ratio for (1)/(n(n+2)) idk if you are able to use the same method for that one my mans? well thanks :)

Comment: The series $\frac{1}{n(n+2)}$ is not geometric, so it doesn't have a common ratio. Though it is possible to find a closed form for the partial sums of the series.

Comment: could you please explain the first part? with that thingymajig equaling the sum of those two "series"?

Comment: oh yeah tahts right, thanks! :d.. im so stupid. brain not working atm :8

Comment: Well if you find my solution satisfactory, make sure to hit the check mark -- it lets others know that the question is answered properly and declutters the forum.